# keep getting an error when trying to add a game over screen in unity2d

Tags: c#, 2d

i'm trying to make a 2d platformer in unity and am trying to make it so that when the player falls off the cliff it shows the game over screen, however I keep getting the error code:

> "Assets\Script\ShowDeath.cs(13,22): error CS1061: 'Transform' does not contain a definition for 'postion' and no accessible extension method 'postion' accepting a first argument of type 'Transform' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

heres the code

```
float deathArea = -4f;
public GameObject deathUI;

void Update()
{
      if(transform.postion.y <= deathArea)
      {
            deathUI.SetActive(true);
      }
}
```

pretty simple code, I just can't figure out what the error means

Comment: The error just means "Transform" doesn't have anything called "position", but the script you posted here uses "transform" (small t) should be fine, are you sure this is a script that causes the problem?

Comment: yes 100% sure because the error code says the name of the script shows "Assets\Script\ShowDeath.cs" and ShowDeath is the name of the script,

also there are only like 2 scripts so far, a character controller and the death script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out I spelt "position" wrong and wrote "postion" so unity didn't know what I was trying to say